# Good php script for uploading profiles pictures and generates different sizes?

Tags: php, file-upload

i want to implement a php script on my registration form in order to let my users upload their images but i also want after the upload generate 3 files, one 50x50px, one 150x150px, and the original size. Can any one suggest me a good script to do this? Thanks!

Comment: /me uploads a 13×11 image and runs away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something like [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) or [timthumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) to generate on the fly? They use caching so you don't keep regenerating the images. This way you aren't confined to 3 sizes either.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use something like timthumb image crop. see project here http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/

Answer (score 0):

and storing them as blob or base64 in a database is also good

you can also use the php module gdlib or imagemagick